# Adding menu to Odoo 10 in custom module

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I want to add a submenu to **Settings->Technical** menu in Odoo 10.
I have tried with the following code, apparently the menu item is loaded (you can see that it is one of the menus created by the custom module) but it is not displayed.

Any tip/suggestion on why?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<odoo>
    <menuitem id="sale_order_custom_document"
              name="Sale Order Custom Documen"
              parent="base.menu_custom"
    />
</odoo>
```

Thanks

Comment: May be you not created any action of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define the action in menuitem then only it is visible.   menuitem without any action will became normal string for display purpose.  So either add sub menu with action or directly assign any action to it.

```
<menuitem name="Sale Order Custom Document" action="<your_action_id>" id="sale_order_custom_document" parent="base.menu_custom" sequence="20"/>
```

Here's a description link for [odoo action](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/saas-13/reference/actions.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. you must also create the actions 's record named:

   `product.product_template_action_custom_docs` for example
2. declare your menu just after

Try this:

```
<odoo>
  <data>
     <!-- your initial code in your <app>_view.xml -->
     <record id="product.product_template_action_custom_docs" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Sale Order Custom Document</field>
        <field name="res_model">product.template</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,kanban,form</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="context">{"search_default_filter_to_sell":1}</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
           <p> here you write the help form your form</p>
        </field>
     </record>

        <!-- after the action, you can now paste your menu declaration
        your specified "action", "id","name","sequence" and "parent"-->

       <menuitem action="product.product_template_action_custom_docs" 
        id="sale_order_custom_document"  parent="base.menu_custom" sequence="20" name="Sale Order Custom Document" />
  </data>
<odoo>
```